# Is Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) impacted by Calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek()?

Tags: java, calendar

Maybe a stupid question, but I have a question I didn't find in the Java documentation.

Does the value of `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` change based on any value change of `Calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek()`?

Or does `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` always give the correct answer (based on the current locale)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the value of `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` change based on any value change of `Calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek()`

No. Sunday is Sunday (`Calendar.SUNDAY`), regardless of whether that's the first day of the week, the second or the seventh. (If you're using a non-Gregorian calendar which may have entirely different week days, that's a different matter of course.)

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek()` does not affect the value of `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`. What it affects is probably `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` because the first day of the week is considered when calculating the current week number.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the `DAY_OF_WEEK` constant actually says:

> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the week. This field takes values SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, and SATURDAY.

This means that the values returned from `get` for this constant are *not* interpreted as ordinal numbers. These are all (static) constants in the `Calendar` class. The fact that they evaluate to 1,2,3 shouldn't confuse you. They mean "Sunday, Monday, Tuesday", not "First day, second day, third day".